# Template v-slot changes v-data-table values?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I am trying to display data of the row clicked in console, I am using a currencyhelpers library that is running RPC calls and getting data from it which gets displayed on my `v-data-table`.

To create a clickable row I am using `<template v-slot:item` which handles a `@click` even on table row click, The problem is as follows: The image below is before I add the v-slot in my `v-data-table` which is fine as it should be

[image]

Here is the `v-data-table after I add the` <template v-slot:item`

[image]

This is my entire component code (with the help of chatGPT:

```
<template>
  <v-layout>
    <v-row>
      <v-col>
        <h1>Currencies</h1>
        <v-container class="mx-auto pa-6">
          <v-data-table 
            :items="currencies" 
            :headers="headers" 
            dense
          >
            <template v-slot:top>
              <v-toolbar flat>
                <v-toolbar-title>Version {{ info.VRSCversion }}</v-toolbar-title>
              </v-toolbar>
            </template>
            <template v-slot:item="{ item }">
              <tr @click="handleCurrencyClick(item)">
                <td v-for="(value, key) in item" :key="key">{{ value }}</td>
              </tr>
            </template>
          </v-data-table>
          

        </v-container>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-layout>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import currencyHelpers from '../lib/currencyHelpers';

const info = ref([]);
const currencies = ref([]);
const headers = [
  { title: 'Name', value: 'currencydefinition.fullyqualifiedname' },
  { title: 'ID', value: 'currencydefinition.currencyid' },
  { title: 'ID rego fee', value: 'currencydefinition.idregistrationfees' },
  { title: 'ID import fee', value: 'currencydefinition.idimportfees' },
  { title: 'Converter Name', value: 'currencydefinition.gatewayconvertername' },
  { title: 'Proof Protocol', value: 'currencydefinition.proofprotocol' },
  { title: 'Options', value: 'currencydefinition.options' }
];
const selectedCurrency = ref({});
const currencyState = ref({});

(async () => {
  info.value = await currencyHelpers.getInfo();
  currencies.value = await currencyHelpers.listCurrencies();
})();

const handleCurrencyClick = async (currency) => {
  const clickedCurrency = currency.value;
  selectedCurrency.value = clickedCurrency;
  console.log("Clicked currency:", clickedCurrency);
  try {
    if (clickedCurrency.currencydefinition) { // Check if currencydefinition exists
      const currencyDefinition = clickedCurrency.currencydefinition.fullyqualifiedname;
      // Call getCurrencyState with the appropriate currency ID or name
      currencyState.value = await currencyHelpers.getCurrencyState(currencyDefinition.fullyqualifiedname);
      console.log("Currency state:", currencyState.value);
    } else {
      console.error("Currency definition not found");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching currency state:", error);
    currencyState.value = null; // Set currency state to null in case of error
  }
};


</script>
```

[JSON DATA](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Comment: you could always ask for additional help on the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78196638) rather than make a new one.  To answer you though, the v-for loops over each key-value of an object, but based on your header definitions it looks like all your data is in an object of an object ... `'currencydefinition.fullyqualifiedname'`.  your v-for only loops once since currencydefinition is the only property on `item`.  you need to loop the properties of item.currencydefinition: `v-for="(value, key) in item.currencydefinition"`

Comment: Does not work, still does the same

Comment: Well am I incorrect in your `item` definition?  Provide some example values, as it's the only way to know how your code is really working.  Without knowing what the input data is we can only guess why you get a certain output.  Provide a Vue Playground if you can, [example showing what I tried](https://shorturl.at/joD01)

Comment: I have created a result.JSON in the playground link I have updated with my question.I have pasted the JSON result, I get 17 of these from the listCurrencies method, in the JSON currencydefintion is what I am getting displayed over the data table

Comment: You have way more properties than you do columns. You need to format the incoming JSON so the properties of item.currencydefinition matches your table headers. the v-for is a dumb loop. It just increments by 1 and displays whatever the the next object property is in the loop.  Given 100 properties and only 7 columns, the v-for will display whatever the **first** 7 of 100 properties are of the object.  Given the same X number of properties matching the same X number of headers then you will find that the column data matches your object data...

Comment: So now what can I do about it?